# Calling a javascript function in a href redirects with firefox, but works with chrome

Tags: javascript, mozilla

[image]

I have code like this

```
<a class="k-button k-button-icontext Gross" href="javascript:territoryTitleListViewModel.titleTerritoryKendoViewModel.GrossesTabView('#=data.CurrentTab#')" style="font-weight: normal;"><span class=" ">Grosses</span></a>
```

`territoryTitleListViewModel` is a javascript inside that `titleTerritoryKendoViewModel` is a child script and the `GrossesTabView` is available in child tab. I am passing the current tab value on click. It's working fine but it's giving error in mozilla. Attached the screen shot same.

```
self.GrossesTabView = function (currentTab) {
        if (currentTab != TitleTerritoryTabsEnum.GROSSES) {
            self.DirtyCheckMethod(currentTab);

            self.parentViewModel.SubTabSelected(TitleTerritoryTabsEnum.GROSSES)

            self.GrossEditClicked(false);
            //getFormatsFilters(); //MG-63 Changes
            self.GrossesView(currentTab);
            self.setColor(TitleTerritoryTabsEnum.GROSSES);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The above code is available in titleTerritoryKendoViewModel and which returns false always

Comment: Use proper event handler binding then, instead of `href="javascript:…"`

Comment: If your question is answered, please accept an answer and close the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You really should avoid javascript: URLs and use proper event binding.

But in answer to your question, you probably need to add the "return" in to make sure it's passed back properly, like this...

```
<a class="k-button k-button-icontext Gross" href="javascript:return territoryTitleListViewModel.titleTerritoryKendoViewModel.GrossesTabView('#=data.CurrentTab#')" style="font-weight: normal;"><span class=" ">Grosses</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a click-event and call the function from there. I put the currentTab in a data-* attribute. With event.preventDefault() even firefox won't follow the link.

I added jQuery because it's nicer as using pure JS.

```js
$(".Gross").click(function(event){
  var data = $(this).data("tab");
  console.log("currentTab: ", data);
  // territoryTitleListViewModel.titleTerritoryKendoViewModel.GrossesTabView(data);
  // do not follow link
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="k-button k-button-icontext Gross" href="#" data-tab="#=data.CurrentTab#" style="font-weight: normal;"><span class=" ">Grosses</span></a>
```